# C socket reconnect

Tags: c, sockets, reconnect

After two days of trying to create client socket that reconnects to a server I would like to ask you for help.

I.E. I am launching a server and a client. Than I kill the server and want that client to try to reconnect until I start the server again.

I have a function `socketcreate` which returns `socket_fd` which I use to first connect (and it works).

But when the server dies and I close the previous `socket_fd` and I try to `reconnect` using
`socketcreate` I got an error `Bad file descriptor`.

But why? I've closed previous `socket_fd` and I am launching the function once again to start new connection.

....

```
while(1) {

  send(sock_fd, buf, strlen(buf),0);

  if( (numbytes = recv(sock_fd, buf, strlen(buf),0) == 0){

   close(sock_fd);

   sock_fd = createsocket();

}
```

1. is that ok to recognize lost connection (i've read that yes). Or SIGPIPE will be better to recognize lost connection during send()?
2. What about reconnecting in while(1) ?

Comment: Show us your code, please..

Comment: If you are using unix socket file then remove/delete that file before execute server (*or remove before bind in server*), If net-socket then SO_REUSEADDR

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: `SO_REUSEADDR` refers to reusing an address (192.168.0.1:12345 for example), not to reusing an already `close()`ed socket.

Comment: show us the `createsocket` function

Comment: Who is giving you the error message "Bad file descriptor"? Which function returns this error?

Answer (score 3):

> After two days of trying to create client socket that reconnects to a server

Stop right there. It is impossible to reconnect a socket.